# dblclick not working on Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, cordova

the android WebView seems not to trigger my dblclick handler when i doubleclick.

```
function main(){

    $('body').dblclick(function(){alert('body dbl')})
}
$(main)
```

on the pc it works, but not on android )-:

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to enable the javascript on your webview in android like this :

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```